# Decimation in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, xcode, signal-processing

Dear Stack Community,

I'm doing a DSP exercise to complement my C++ FIR lowpass filter with filter coefficients designed in  and exported from Matlab. The DSP exercise in question is the act of decimating the output array of the FIR lowpass filter to a lower sample rate by a factor of 'M'. In C++ I made a successful but extremely simple implementation within a .cpp file and I've been trying hard to convert it to a function to which I can give the output array of the FIR filter. Here is the very basic version of the code:

```
int n = 0;
int length = 50;
int M = 12;
float array[length];
float array2[n];


for (int i = 0 ; i<length; i++) {
    array[i] = std::rand();
}
for (int i = 0; i<length; i=i+M) {
    array2[n++] = array[i];
}

for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
    std::cout << i << " " << array2[i] << std::endl;
}
```

As you can see very simple. My attempt to convert this to a function using  is unfortunately not working. Here is the function as is:

```
std::vector<float> decimated_array(int M,std::vector<float> arr){
    size_t n_idx = 0;
    std::vector<float> decimated(n_idx);

    for (int i = 0; i<(int)arr.size(); i = i + M) {
        decimated[n_idx++] = arr[i];
    }
    return decimated;
}
```

This produces a very common Xcode error of EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using this section of code in the .cpp file. The error occurs in the line 'decimated[n_idx++] = arr[i];' specifically:

```
int length = 50;
int M = 3;
std::vector<float> fct_array(length);

for (int i = 0 ; i<length; i++) {
    fct_array[i] = std::rand();
}

FIR_LPF test;
std::vector<float> output;

output = test.decimated_array(M,fct_array);
```

I'm trying to understand what is incorrect with my application of  or perhaps just my translation of the algorithm into a more general setting. Any help with this matter would be greatly appreciated and hopefully this is clear enough for the community to understand.

Regards, Vhaanzeit

Comment: `decimated[n_idx++] = arr[i];`  -- Your `decimated` vector is empty.  You can't just access items in an empty vector like that.  Replace that line with `decimated.at(n_idx++) = arr[i];` and you will now get an `out_of_range` exception, much more informative than an access violation error.

Comment: Was not expecting such a quick response. Thanks for the quick reply and this is conceptually really helpful and seems like a bit of a rookie error. Will try to figure out a solution to this! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue:

```
size_t n_idx = 0;
std::vector<float> decimated(n_idx);
```

You did not size the vector before you used it, thus you were invoking undefined behavior when assigning to element 0, 1, etc. of the `decimated` vector.

What you could have done is in the loop, call `push_back`:

```
std::vector<float> decimated_array(int M,std::vector<float> arr)
{
    std::vector<float> decimated;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arr.size(); i = i + M) {
        decimated.push_back(arr[i]);
    }
    return decimated;
}
```

The `decimated` vector starts out empty, but a new item is added with the `push_back` call.

Also, you should pass the `arr` vector by `const` reference, not by value.

```
std::vector<float> decimated_array(int M, const std::vector<float>& arr);
```

Passing by (const) reference does not invoke a copy.

Edit: Changed loop counter to correct type, thus not needing the cast.

Comment: Thanks an awful lot for the help. I guess this comes down to being unfamiliar with C++. I've been thinking in terms of traditional C a bit too much which is the problem here. Will need to get used to using these templates a bit more. Once again really appreciated!

Comment: @Vhaanzeit Give the man an upvote and mark the question as solved if the answer helped and solved the problem.